# Javascript Intl.NumberFormat Currency without comma

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is there a way in Javascript/Typescript to format currency without a comma using `Intl.NumberFormat`?
Right now, its display as 1,000.00. Want to make it 1000.00

```
export const formatCurrency = (item: number) => {
  const currencyFormat = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'USD',
  });
  return currencyFormat.format(item);
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `useGrouping` to `false`:

```
export const formatCurrency = (item: number) => {
  const currencyFormat = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'USD',
    useGrouping: false,
  });
  return currencyFormat.format(item);
};
```

Found in the docs: [Intl.NumberFormat constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat)

note: `useGrouping` is marked as experimental

Answer (score 2):

If you simply want the dollar amount and the cents, just format the value with the `Number.prototype.toFixed` method and pass the value `2`.

Did you want to include the dollar (`$`) sign?

```js
console.log((1000).toFixed(2));
```

---

#### Hiding the grouping separator

As [vr. mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75595197/1762224), you can use the experimental `useGrouping` config and set it to `false` (default is `auto`). As a side node, you should store your formatter or configure it on the spot when calling `Number.prototype.toLocaleString`.

```js
const currencyFormatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'USD',
  useGrouping: false
});

// Convenience function, can be removed
const formatCurrency = (item) => currencyFormatter.format(item);

console.log(formatCurrency(1000)); // or currencyFormatter.format(1000)
```

Or:

```js
const formatCurrency = (item) => item.toLocaleString('en-US', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'USD',
  useGrouping: false
});

console.log(formatCurrency(1000));
```

Stick with one of the two ways above. If you are formatting many numbers, the first is a better choice.